# efficient way to join 65,000 .csv files

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia

I have say 65,000 .csv files that I need to work with in julia language.

The goal is to perform basic statistics on the data set.

I had some ways of joining all the data sets

```
#1 - set a common index and leftjoin() - perform statistics row wise 
#2 - vcat() the dataframes on top of each other - vertically stacked use group by
```

Eitherway the final data frames are very large ! and become slow in processing

Is there an efficient way of doing this ?

I thought of performing either #1 or #2 and splitting the joining operations in thirds, lets say after 20,000 joins save to .csv and operate in chunks then at the end join all 3 in one last operation.

Well not sure how to replicate making 65k .csv files but basically below I loop through the files in the directory, load the csv then `vcat()` to one df. Question more relating to if there is a better way to manage the size of the operation. `vcat()` makes something grow. Ahead of time maybe I can cycle through the .csv files, obtain file dimensions per .csv, initialize the full dataframe to final output size, then cycle through each .csv row by row and populate the initialized df.

```
using CSV
using DataFrames

# read all files in directory
csv_dir_tmax = cd(readdir, "C:/Users/andrew.bannerman/Desktop/Julia/scripts/GHCN data/ghcnd_all_csv/tmax")

# initialize outputs
tmax_all = DataFrame(Date = [], TMAX = [])
c=1
for c = 1:length(csv_dir_tmax)
    print("Starting csv file ", csv_dir_tmax[c]," - Iteration ",c,"\n")
        if c <= length(csv_dir_tmax)
    csv_tmax = CSV.read(join(["C:/Users/andrew.bannerman/Desktop/Julia/scripts/GHCN data/ghcnd_all_csv/tmax/", csv_dir_tmax[c]]), DataFrame, header=true)
        tmax_all = vcat(tmax_all, csv_tmax)
    end
end
```

Comment: If you would want to get a reliable suggestion can you please share the code you use now and then it can be investigated. In general it seems from your description that the aggregation you perform can be done on per-file way so why would you want to perform it otherwise. In general my assumption is that the performance bottleneck will be IO not data processing.

Comment: The high-level idea would be multi-threaded loading and vcat, and then aggregating it properly, but it's hard to provide good advice with such general problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach should be relatively efficient (assuming that data fits into memory):

```
tmax_all = reduce(vcat, [CSV.read("YOUR_DIR$x", DataFrame) for x in csv_dir_tmax])
```

Comment: The trick is that `reduce` has a special path for `vcat` (not only in DataFrames.jl but also in Julia Base) that makes it allocate only once for all containers passed.

Answer (score 0):

initializing the final output to the total size of final output (like vcat() would finally build). Then populate it element wise seems to be working way better:

```
# get the dimensions of each .csv files
tmax_all_total_output_size = fill(0, size(csv_dir_tmax,1))
tmin_all_total_output_size = fill(0, size(csv_dir_tmin,1))
tavg_all_total_output_size = fill(0, size(csv_dir_tavg,1))
tmax_dim = Int64[]
tmin_dim = Int64[]
tavg_dim = Int64[]
c=1
for c = 1:length(csv_dir_tmin) # 47484 - last point
    print("Starting csv file ", csv_dir_tmin[c]," - Iteration ",c,"\n")
        if c <= length(csv_dir_tmax)
    tmax_csv = CSV.read(join(["C:/Users/andrew.bannerman/Desktop/Julia/scripts/GHCN data/ghcnd_all_csv/tmax/", csv_dir_tmax[c] ]), DataFrame, header=true)
    global tmax_dim = size(tmax_csv,1)
        tmax_all_total_output_size[c] = tmax_dim
    end
    if c <= length(csv_dir_tmin)
    tmin_csv = CSV.read(join(["C:/Users/andrew.bannerman/Desktop/Julia/scripts/GHCN data/ghcnd_all_csv/tmin/", csv_dir_tmin[c]]), DataFrame, header=true)
    global tmin_dim = size(tmin_csv,1)
        tmin_all_total_output_size[c] = tmin_dim
    end
    if c <= length(csv_dir_tavg)
    tavg_csv = CSV.read(join(["C:/Users/andrew.bannerman/Desktop/Julia/scripts/GHCN data/ghcnd_all_csv/tavg/", csv_dir_tavg[c]]), DataFrame, header=true)
    global tavg_dim = size(tavg_csv,1)
        tavg_all_total_output_size[c] = tavg_dim
    end
end

# sum total dimension of all .csv files
tmax_sum = sum(tmax_all_total_output_size)
tmin_sum = sum(tmin_all_total_output_size)
tavg_sum = sum(tavg_all_total_output_size)

# initialize final output to total final dimension
tmax_date_array = fill(Date("13000101", "yyyymmdd"),tmax_sum)
tmax_array = zeros(tmax_sum)
tmin_date_array = fill(Date("13000101", "yyyymmdd"),tmin_sum)
tmin_array = zeros(tmin_sum)
tavg_date_array = fill(Date("13000101", "yyyymmdd"),tavg_sum)
tavg_array = zeros(tavg_sum)

# initialize outputs
tmax_all = DataFrame(Date = tmax_date_array, TMAX = tmax_array)
tmin_all = DataFrame(Date = tmin_date_array, TMIN = tmin_array)
tavg_all = DataFrame(Date = tavg_date_array, TAVG = tavg_array)
tmax_count = 0
tmin_count = 0
tavg_count = 0
```

Then begin filling the initialized df.

Comment: final .csv file export is 3.5GB for tmax